# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library

Tags: java, java-native-interface

My Mac ARM Laptop is failing to load the second library below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        System.load("/Users/orlando/libbinaryen.dylib");
        System.load("/Users/orlando/libfingerprints.dylib");
    }
}

>> Hello world!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /Users/orlando/libfingerprints.dylib
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2393)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

I've tried both a library I've built and a library someone else built on their ARM Mac that works on their machine (and someone else's). Nobody can figure out why this is happening.

We've confirmed file permissions, file location, processor type, etc.  We've also tried various debugging / output attempts like

```
java -Djava.library.path=/Users/orlando/Git/lib -verbose:jni -classpath /Users/orlando/Git/HelloWorld/out/production/HelloWorld Main

:
[0.119s][debug][jni,resolve] [Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace ... JNI]
Exception in thread "main" [0.119s][debug][jni,resolve] [Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.System.identityHashCode ... JNI]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /Users/orlando/libfingerprints.dylib
[0.120s][debug][jni,resolve] [Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.StackTraceElement.initStackTraceElements ... JNI]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2393)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Can anyone suggest anything off the beaten path I can try or verify?

Thanks in advance...

Extra information:

```
>> file libfingerprints.dylib
libfingerprints.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64

>> otool -L libfingerprints.dylib
libfingerprints.dylib:
  @rpath/libfingerprints.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
  /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1500.65.0)
  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1319.100.3)

>> uname -m arm64

>> java --version
openjdk version "17.0.4.1" 2022-08-12 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-17.0.4.9.1 (build 17.0.4.1+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-17.0.4.9.1 (build 17.0.4.1+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Just for context..  

>> file libfingerprints.dylib 
libfingerprints.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64



>> otool -L libfingerprints.dylib 
libfingerprints.dylib:
 @rpath/libfingerprints.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
 /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1500.65.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1319.100.3)


 >> uname -m
arm64

Comment: Looking at the source code, there are several cases in which `null` is returned, which result in an exception. You could step through the code with a debugger to find out which case you're in. That particular exception seems to be thrown from: `ClassLoader::loadLibrary(Class<?>,File)`

Comment: I've only been able to follow it to  return load(this, name, isBuiltin, isJNI, loadLibraryOnlyIfPresent) in NativeLibraryImpl.  It's just returning null... I don't know how to step into there or tell what (if anything) is going on in the c++ side of the universe.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? The latest version of `load` returns a boolean.

Comment: Also, I'm not very familiar with Mac, but this might be a result of an OS dependent library loading error, which is translated into the exception you're seeing. You could try creating a simple C program that tries to `dlopen` the library, and see if that works. Running with `-Xlog:os -Xlog:library` might also show something useful.

Comment: @JornVernee `System.load()` returns `void`, and it hasn't changed in 25 years. What do you mean by 'the latest version'?

Comment: @user207421 I'm talking about `load` inside [`jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ad34be1f329edc8e7155983835cc70d733c014b8/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/loader/NativeLibraries.java#L542). The one the OP says is returning `null`. The latest version is returning `boolean`.

Comment: @JornVernee Thank you for the response.. you are correct, I mispoke - the load in NativeLibraries IS returning false.. NativeLibrary just takes that and return null.  If it helps, here's the version of Java I'm using: openjdk version "17.0.4.1" 2022-08-12 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-17.0.4.9.1 (build 17.0.4.1+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-17.0.4.9.1 (build 17.0.4.1+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I will try your C program suggestion, and report back. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've accidentally installed the intel version of java, and because I have rosetta installed, it works, but exhibits a similar issue in being unable to load arm64 binaries. Check if the other library is also only compiled for arm64, and also check that the java version is arm64

Answer (score 1):

Posting an unsatisfying answer, but sometimes you have to move on in life.

For reasons I don't understand, the issue resolved itself after uninstalling Correto Java 17 and installing OpenJDK 17 via Homebrew.  This is puzzling because our production instance uses Correto, and another developer who has no issues with this is using Correto (albeit on an Intel based Mac).  Maybe this is an issue with Correto on a Mac Arm or maybe just the act of reinstalling fixed things on it's own.

Comment: If the latter, it would be interesting to see what would happen if you uninstalled OpenJDK 17 and reinstalled Correto Java 17. Note: "on its own", no apostrophe.